# WPF tab control dynamically load another xbap

Tags: wpf, xbap

I am tasked to develop a Tab control which would dynamically load another xbap.  The only way I see possible is that add a WebBrowser object to the tab, and make that browser navigate to the 2nd xbap.  So the structure will be a browser contains xbap which contains another browser  with another xbap.

Is it the best practice with that structure?

Thanks!